# Constructing Ray class fields of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and division points of lemniscate

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I've heard that it was Abel who first constructed some of (or all of?) Abelian extensions of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ using division points of lemniscates. Can we construct the Ray class fields of $Q(i)$, or give some useful practical information on Ray class fields of a field $K$?

Can anyone explain more about the division points of lemniscate and abelian extensions of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$?

Comment: You may look it up in Silverman-Tate.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer I think your comment prepared a good answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Roberta Lubiana's [thesis](https://algant.eu/documents/theses/lubiana.pdf) provides the details.